# JSTL String Compare with ArrayList element

Tags: jsp, if-statement, arraylist, jstl

Using this code

```
  <c:forEach var="row" varStatus="loop" items="${court.monday}">
<tr>
<c:choose>
<c:when test='${row eq "Free Court"}'>
<td class="inner">${loop.index} is Bookable </td>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<td class="inner">${row}</td>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Essentially, I have a Timetable object, which contains 7 ArrayLists of Strings. I can loop through the list with just

```
<td class="inner">${row}</td>
```

but I want to check if the row value equals 'Free Court'. If it does, a link appears. If it doesn't, the event is displayed. I am getting the following error.

'${court.monday}' Property 'monday' not found on type java.lang.String

I assume this is something to do with comparing an ArrayList to a String, but I've tried stuff like row[loop.index] (which is displaying correctly if I just output it.

This is the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/gotoCourt", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String chooseCourt(Model model, HttpServletRequest request){
        model.addAttribute("court", timetableService.getById(request.getParameter("courtID")));
        return "court";
    }
```

The Timetable class is

```
public class MonaleenTTV1 implements Timetable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Size(min=5, max=10, message="Court must be between 5 and 10 characters",groups={PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class})
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    //@Min(value = 1, message="Value must be 1 or greater")
    private int slots;

    private int startTime;

    private int endTime;

    private boolean enabled;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable (name = "monday", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
    List<String> monday;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable (name = "tuesday", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
    List<String> tuesday;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable (name = "wednesday", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
    List<String> wednesday;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable (name = "thursday", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
    List<String> thursday;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable (name = "friday", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
    List<String> friday;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable (name = "saturday", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
    List<String> saturday;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable (name = "sunday", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
    List<String> sunday;
```

Comment: you're showing us code that doesn't cause the problem. court is a String, and there is no getMonday() method in String. That's what the message tells you. Given that we don't have any idea where and how you get court from, we can't help.

Comment: court is a Timetable object, which contains 7 ArrayLists of Strings (court.monday is mondays list etc) I've updated the post to show the controller and the timetable partial class

Comment: Essentially, I can loop through each list, and display each list with no issues, but I want to compare each entry in each list to a certain value and change my action to either display the list item or a different link in some cases.

Comment: try once with "==" instead of "eq"

Comment: I tried that and same issue with court.monday

Answer (score 0):

Ugh! There's nothing wrong with my code. A restart of Tomcat made it work! :)